# Intellij compile & export jar to another server

Tags: intellij-idea, compilation

I use intellij idea and i want to compile my app into a jar format and imediatly export to a external server.

It's possible ?

Thanks you ;)

Comment: What build system are you using (maven, grade, ant-ivy) ? Are you talking about a fat/uber jar if your project has dependencies? What do you mean by export ( for example SSH to a remote server )?  What have you tried doing on your own that hasn't worked?

Comment: I use the default intellij export system.